# How do I remove a table named following a keyword in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I accidentally named a table 'order'.
Since 'order by' is a keyword phrase, I am unable to delete this table:

```
> drop table order;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...
```

How do I drop the table ?

Comment: Not sure about this but have you tried back ticks around order? `\`order\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [identifier quote character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) is the backtick (“`”):

```
drop table `order`;
```

Comment: This is one of those questions that tends to attract a heap of duplicate answers. +1 to this one for including a little explanation and a link to further info.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
drop table `order`;
```

Tested and working on mysql :)

Answer (score 1):

Using backticks around the table name:

```
drop table `order`;
```

will work.